# Does Lightroom remember or save a 'custom order' after closing?

Tags: lightroom

I've researched and read responses to sort order questions but have not been able to find out if LR will automatically save or remember your custom sort order after closing. Does anyone know if each folder can have one saved custom order in the dropdown? Thanks, Mike.

Comment: I guess my question is will Lightroom save or remember a Custom Order after closing the program. So if I drag files around they'll still be in that order? I know the other sorts are all based on name, date, time etc. and would all work again.

Comment: Yes, your custom order is still maintained as well.

Comment: Honestly, isn't this something that can simply be tested much faster than asking a quesion on SE and wait for answers?

Answer (score 1):

**Each folder has its own sorting order.** There is a default but once you change it, the folder keeps being sorted in that order until the sort is changed again. This applies to custom orders and presets such as *Capture Time*, *Added Order*, etc.

This unfortunately can get confusing since Lightroom shows the contents of folders recursively and the sort order shown is a property of the selected folder. So if you are on a directory sorted by Time and you then select its parent directory which is sorted by Filename, then the order of the images is going to change in addition to showing any images present in other sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, folders will remember the prior selected sort order.